# Elastic Search Filter Bucket Values

Tags: java, database, elasticsearch, nosql, backend

My use case is as follows, I need to find out all the unique colors that had appeared in last 1 year but went disappearing in last 3 months. So my documents looks like this

```
{
 doc_id: 1,
 color: "red",
 timestamp: epoch time here
},
{
 doc_id: 2,
 color: "blue",
 timestamp: epoch time here
}
```

So For example if any document with attribute color (from now referred to just as color) blue appeared in last year, but didn't appear in the last 3 months then we need to include blue in the result. On the other hand if documents with color red appeared in  last year and also appeared in the last 3 months then we need to exclude red from the result.

The 1 year in the above example also includes the 3 months in it when computing. So if all the documents with Color blue happened only between May 2018 - Feb 2019, this means that documents with blue occurred in last year but went missing in last 3 months (March 2019 - May 2019), then blue should be in the result set. On the other hand if the documents with Color Red happened between May 2018 - Feb 2019 as well as March 2019 - May 2019, then we need to exclude this color red in the result set.  I couldn't get this with terms query in Elastic search.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a range from "2019-01-01"- "2019-12-30", with excluded months as "2019-09-01"- "2019-12-30"

```
Mapping :
{
  "testindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "color" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "doc_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "GPv0zWoB8AL5aj8D_wLG",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "doc_id" : 1,
          "color" : "blue",
          "timestamp" : "2019-03-30"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Gfv1zWoB8AL5aj8DJAKU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "doc_id" : 1,
          "color" : "red",
          "timestamp" : "2019-12-30"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Gvv1zWoB8AL5aj8DOwKf",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "doc_id" : 1,
          "color" : "red",
          "timestamp" : "2019-01-01"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Final Query:

```
GET testindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2019-01-01",
        "lte": "2019-12-30"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "excluded_range": {
          "date_range": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": "2019-09-01",
                "to": "2019-12-31"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "excluded_docs_count": {
          "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "excluded_range>_count"
          }
        },
        "myfinal": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "out_of_range_docs": "excluded_docs_count"
            },
            "script": {
              "inline": "params.out_of_range_docs==0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```